# How to list the resultset based on order using query

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

```
//===================================================================================
- ( NSMutableDictionary * ) getDataToDisplayTierTwo:(NSString*)dbPath:(NSString*)iD{
//===================================================================================
    NSMutableDictionary *aTierTwoTemplateData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {

        NSString *selectSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"select * from sub_categories_reference scr inner join storyboard_sub_categories ssc on ssc.id = scr.sub_category_id inner join subcategory_order as sco on sco.sub_category_id = scr.sub_category_id where  scr.main_category_id = %@ and sco.main_category_id = %@ order by sco.position asc",iD,iD];

        NSLog(@"%@", selectSQL);

        const char *sql_query_stmt = [selectSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql_query_stmt, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {

            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {
                NSString *aValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                    (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 6)];

                NSString *aId = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                 (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 5)];


               [aTierTwoTemplateData setObject:aId forKey:aValue];

                [aValue release];
                [aId release];

                NSLog(@"%@ %@ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^picker value id ", aValue, aId);

            }
        }
    }   
    sqlite3_close(database); 


    return aTierTwoTemplateData;
}
```

I am able to get the resultset when i assign this to array , but it loses the order in which , i have stored in the dictionery.

Actually , i have stored the result set based on the position field .

When i assign the resultset into array , the order gets changed.

Please let me know how can i handle this situation.

This is not a duplicate, as i have a coulmn in the db as "position"

Comment: NSDictionary sorts its keys, so if you want the data to be in exact order, try to use NSArray/NSMutableArray to store data and maintain the order.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store data as key-value pair and maintain the order, then you can use combination of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`.
The same code will be:

```
//===================================================================================
- ( NSArray * ) getDataToDisplayTierTwo:(NSString*)dbPath:(NSString*)iD{
//===================================================================================
    NSMutableArray *aTierTwoTemplateData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {

        NSString *selectSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"select * from sub_categories_reference scr inner join storyboard_sub_categories ssc on ssc.id = scr.sub_category_id inner join subcategory_order as sco on sco.sub_category_id = scr.sub_category_id where  scr.main_category_id = %@ and sco.main_category_id = %@ order by sco.position asc",iD,iD];

        NSLog(@"%@", selectSQL);

        const char *sql_query_stmt = [selectSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql_query_stmt, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {

            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {
                NSString *aValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                    (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 6)];

                NSString *aId = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                 (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 5)];



               [aTierTwoTemplateData addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:aId forKey:aValue]];

                [aValue release];
                [aId release];

                NSLog(@"%@ %@ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^picker value id ", aValue, aId);

            }
        }
    }   
    sqlite3_close(database); 

    return [aTierTwoTemplateData autorelease];
}
```

In this way you'll be having an array of dictionaries, where your values will be stored in the dictionary and the order of the data also will be preserved.